# How to get absolute path from popup (Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) kivy , andoid -11

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyjnius

I am a beginner programmer, writing my first application in kivy. And ran into limited storage issue for android - 11 (API 30). How to get the absolute path from the pop-up window when the user selects the folder to save the application data in which I am going to store some data. My application works fine without this choice on 9 anroid, but here's the problem.

here is the minimal code from that window. How to get the absolute path 'root_id' for further manipulations with this folder. By creating files in it and opening SaveDialoga in kivy

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import os
from android import activity, mActivity
from jnius import autoclass
from kivy.app import App
from jnius import cast
from android.storage import app_storage_path, primary_external_storage_path, secondary_external_storage_path

Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
DocumentsContract = autoclass('android.provider.DocumentsContract')
Document = autoclass('android.provider.DocumentsContract$Document')

class Demo(App):
    REQUEST_CODE = 42 # unique request ID
   
    def set_intent(self):
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, self.REQUEST_CODE)        

    def intent_callback(self, requestCode, resultCode, intent):
        if requestCode == self.REQUEST_CODE:
            msg = ""
            root_uri = intent.getData()
            print(root_uri.getPath())
            #  /tree/primary:CarInWay

            root_id = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(root_uri)
            print( root_id)
            #  primary:CarInWay

            from pathlib import Path
            p = Path(root_uri.getPath()).resolve()
            print(p, p.is_dir(), p.is_absolute())
            #  /tree/primary:CarInWay False True

            p = Path(root_id).resolve()
            print( p, p.is_dir(), p.is_absolute())
            #   /data/data/car.carinway/files/app/primary:CarInWay False True


            primary_ext_storage = primary_external_storage_path()

            data_dir = str(os.path.join(primary_ext_storage, 'CarInWay'))
            check_data_dir = os.path.exists(data_dir)
            print(data_dir , check_data_dir)
            #  /storage/emulated/0/CarInWay === True

            p = Path(primary_ext_storage + '/CarInWay')
            print('===', p, '===', p.stat().st_mode)
            #  /storage/emulated/0/CarInWay === 16832

            settings_path = app_storage_path()
            secondary_ext_storage = secondary_external_storage_path()
            print(settings_path, primary_ext_storage, secondary_ext_storage)
            #  /data/user/0/car.carinway/files /storage/emulated/0 None

    def on_start(self):
        self.set_intent()

    def build(self):
        activity.bind(on_activity_result=self.intent_callback)
        self.label = Label()

        return self.label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demo().run()
```

Comment: There is no path, as the user does not need to choose a location on the filesystem, let alone one that you can access.

Comment: sorry, I certainly do not fully understand the concept of android. But as far as I read the documentation, and understood this meaning of calling a dialog box, then the user creates a folder there and gives permission to use the application outside the application itself. In which, as I understand it, the application may already notice the data.
Or how can I implement all this. Maybe I'm not approaching this issue correctly

Comment: "then the user creates a folder there and gives permission to use the application outside the application itself." -- yes. However, the "folder" that the user creates does not have to be on the user's device. It can be a cloud storage provider, such as Google Drive. Even if the "folder" resides on the device, it does not necessarily represent a directory that your app can access. For example, it might be managed by an encrypted documents provider.

Comment: I am now reading the forum in more depth on this issue, it is difficult to do this when I do not know java. And I only see the solution if it's local storage.
Please tell me 1) is it possible then to get access by an absolute path (or in some other way), if this is not a local storage, but a cloud or sd - card. 2) how then to restrict the user's choice to only local storage. 3) how can you then solve the problem with access to folders outside the application, "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" - does not allow writing to android 11. Thank you for your help

Comment: "is it possible then to get access by an absolute path (or in some other way), if this is not a local storage, but a cloud or sd - card" -- no. "how then to restrict the user's choice to only local storage" -- that is not possible with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, sorry.

Comment: If you let the user choose a folder with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE then you can later create as much subdirectories and files in that folder as you want. But not with classic file system classes but using the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" - does not allow writing to android 11. ` Yes it does. Not on the root of external storage but in all already available public directories there like Documents, Download, DCIM, Pictures and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the not quite accurate postal question. But my problem is saving the data in non-application folders, so that when the application is updated, they are not overwritten.
The solution to the problem turned out to be simple.

```
context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
path_file = context.getExternalFilesDir(None)
path = path_file.getAbsolutePath()
```

Which made it possible to create a folder in ANDROID / DATA. Where can I already create and store data.